# When I ORDER BY a computed column, the query slows significantly - Can this be sped up?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization

The following query is taking more than 25 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT c.* , (c.age+ (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.newdate))) AS ranking , IF(uc.id_user = 7,1,0) AS favorite
FROM c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN uc ON uc.id_cluster = c.id AND uc.id_user = '7' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN d ON d.id_cluster = c.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dt0 ON dt0.id_document = d.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t0 ON dt0.id_term = t0.id 
WHERE MATCH(t0.normalizacion) AGAINST ('term' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY ranking ASC 
LIMIT 30
```

Indexes:

- c.id PRIMARY
- c.age INDEX
- c.newdate INDEX
- uc.id_user, uc.id_cluster PRIMARY
- d.id PRIMARY
- d.id_cluster INDEX
- dt0.id_document, dt0.id_term PRIMARY
- dt0.id_document INDEX
- dt0.id_term INDEX
- t0.id PRIMARY
- t0.normalizacion FULLTEXT

If I remove the ORDER BY clause, it takes only 2 seconds.

I've been searching and found that the same index has to be used for both GROUP BY and ORDER BY (tried ordering by c.id and took 2 or 3 seconds). How can I change the query to be faster?

Comment: Is 2 seconds acceptable?

Comment: @cheeken Yes. Specially taking into account the current 25 seconds.

Comment: The basic problem here is that you cannot index by ranking because it is calculated in real time. I am not sure about your table structure and what the columns mean but somehow you should try to have a fixed column to order by.

Comment: @cen I tried creating a column c.age2 = c.age-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.newdate) and sorting by it (as UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is a constant and could be removed for sorting purposes). However, this didn't improve the query's time.

Comment: @cen Yes. But I think MySQL can't use that index as it's using c.id for grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(consolidating the discussion above)

You can't order efficiently by a computation result. To make this query work fast, create a `ranking` column that contains `c.age-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.newdate)`. Then create an index on `id` *and* `ranking`, i.e. `CREATE INDEX id_ranking ON c (id, ranking)` to make both GROUP BY and ORDER BY indexed.