# How to sort a table using order by clause in desc order using difference in value of two other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an article table with "article liked" column and "article unliked" column:

```
article Id        | like      | unlike
-------------------------------------------------
      0           | 10        | 2
      1           | 12        | 3
```

Now I want to fetch data in descending order like this:

```
article Id        | Like-Unlike
-------------------------------------------------
      1           | 12-3 =9
      0           | 10-2 =8  ( desc order)
```

Please note that I want to fetch data using difference in value of two column i.e (Like- Unlike).
Please help me how to achieve this functionality in Mysql. If not possible I will make another column with the difference and sort using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by a computed column.

```
select *, like-unlike as customOrder from table order by customOrder desc;
```

Note though that this cannot use indexes so it may be slow if your dataset is large. In such case you can store the computed value as a new, indexed, column. See [When I ORDER BY a computed column, the query slows significantly - Can this be sped up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111020/when-i-order-by-a-computed-column-the-query-slows-significantly-can-this-be-s) for more details